# Start Up error messages?

Tags: boot, error-handling

When I boot my PC on I get the following errors before the login screen.

[   20.371238] Support for cores revisions 0x17 and 0x18 disabled by module param allhwsupport=0.  Try b43.allhwsupport=1

[   21.656204] brcmsmac bcma:0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)

[   21.656266] brcmsmac bcma:0: brcms_config: change power-save mode: false (implement)

How do solve theses?

Comment: So I tried the following method to fix the error, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93738/b43-wireless-driver-error     I don't get the above error any more but now get the following error: [10.033184] b43-phy0 ERROR: FOUND UNSUPPORTED PHY (Analog 10, type 8 (LCN), Revision 1)

Answer (score 0):

i got the same thing but first back up your HDD and then grab your UBUNTU SETUP DISK/DRIVE and use it to go into advanced options (if you can) and select REPAIR